# Can GET a method but POST doesn't work. Any ideas why the method POST isn't uses?

Tags: python, flask, post, get, jinja2

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, redirect

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/doborpompy', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def doborpompy():

    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('doborpompy.html')
    else:
        metry = 200
        if 'metry' in request.form:
            metry = request.form['metry']

        return render_template('doborpompy_wynik.html', metry=metry)
```

> "GET /doborpompy%20method=?metry=44&metry_ogrzewane=44&ilosc_osob=44&typ_domu=pasywny&dofinansowanie=dofinansowanie&budget=standard&zrodlo=ogrzewanie_podlogowe&powietrze_woda=woda HTTP/1.1" 404 -

I can go for an option GET, but when I am trying to POST it still trying to do an GET option.
Any ideas?

Comment: 404 means "that url was not found".  That log file shows that the requested url was `/doborpompy%20method`, not `/doborpompy`.

Comment: `method` is not passed as part of the url, as you seem to expect.

Comment: The problem is with what `url_for("doborpompy")` is returning -- it's returning `/doborpomy method` instead of just `/doborpomy`

Comment: yes but why it's happend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are **not** handling the **POST** Action.
By default when you access the route, you are doing a **GET** Request, so you should handle the **POST** Like This:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, redirect

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/doborpompy', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def doborpompy():

    if request.method == "POST":
        return "<h1>This is how to handle post action in the if statement</h1>"
        # rest of your code ...
    
    return render_template("doborpompy.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

[image]

And you should also edit this line in your `doborpompy.html` file:

`<form id="formularz_doboru" action="{{url_for("doborpompy")}}" method="POST">`

to

`<form id="formularz_doboru" action="{{url_for('doborpompy')}}" method="POST">`

Comment: This seems irrelevant; `request.method` has a value; which one you check for with an explicit comparison shouldn't matter. The OP's request looks suspicious, with the endpoint containing a space.

Comment: Hey @chepner, I'm not sure about the 'endpoint containing a space'; I can't see or figure out what you're mentioning. Regarding `request.method`, what you are saying is correct. At least, I handle my routes like this myself in Flask.

Comment: I'm referring to the `/doborpompy%20method=?...`; `%20method=` appears to be on the wrong side of the `?` in the OP's question. I would expect the `method=` to be on the other side of the `?`.